# How to show all steps in a while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a small project about the Collatz conjecture.

In this project i want to apply the formula " times 3 plus one" when the number is odd and devide a number when its even.

i want to keep looping this until the number is 1 and show not only how many steps it took but also display all the numbers it goes through.

i've gotten quite far i think but i have trouble displaying all the steps the loop goes through.

here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Collatz Conjecture</title>
    <script>

        function findOddEven() {

                var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
                let i = 0;
                while (num !=  1) {
                    if (num % 2 == 0) {
                        num = num / 2; /*even*/
                    } else {
                        num = (num * 3) + 1; /*odd*/
                  console.log(num) }
                    i++
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result is " + num + " found in " + i + " runs";  
                }
            } 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <small>Number:</small><input type="text" id="num" name="num" min="0" /><input type="button" value="submit"
            onclick="findOddEven()" name="find" />
        <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="result"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: use `.innerHTML +=` instead of `.innerHTML = `

Comment: If I put in `7`, what output would you hope to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the numbers in the array and display them at the end. You can also move the `.innerHTML` out of the loop since this only needs to be done when the loop is finished.

I've used [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn the array into a comma seperated string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Collatz Conjecture</title>
    <script>
      function findOddEven() {
        var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
        let steps = [num]; // Store starting number
        let i = 0;
        
        while (num != 1) {
          if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num = num / 2; /*even*/
          } else {
            num = num * 3 + 1; /*odd*/
          }
          
          steps.push(num); // Add changed number to the array
          
          i++;
        }
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            'Result is ' + num + ' found in ' + i + ' runs. Steps taken: ' + steps.join(', ');
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <small>Number:</small
      ><input type="text" id="num" name="num" min="0" /><input
        type="button"
        value="submit"
        onclick="findOddEven()"
        name="find"
      />
      <div style="margin-top: 10px" id="result"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure that the input, `var num`, it's always positive or the loop will hang.

Answer (score -1):

Is your problem not seeing all numbers? If so, your console.log is inside the else statement. To see all numbers you shall move it outside the if else statement.